# Error al tomar foto con cámara al cambiar targetSdkVersion del 22 al 28

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build.gradle

Error al cambiar el targetSdkVersion del 22 al 28. Con el targetSdkVersion 22 No da problemas. Me da el siguiente error al abrir la cámara para tomar la foto:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.sgm.fow.api_face, PID: 22727
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6291)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24931)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6291) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24931) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921) 
                   Caused by: android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/07BD-1914/Android/data/com.sgm.fow.api_face/files/Pictures/IMG_7922254420295645587.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
                      at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1975)
                      at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2363)
                      at android.content.ClipData.prepareToLeaveProcess(ClipData.java:941)
                      at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9944)
                      at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9929)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1622)
                      at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4751)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:767)
                      at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4691)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:754)
                      at com.sgm.fow.api_face.ui.SelectImageActivity.takePhoto(SelectImageActivity.java:115)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6291) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24931) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes presentar las dependencias de tu proyecto

Comment: Gracias por interesarte por mi problema y perdona por no contestar. He seguido investigando y he encontrado la solución. Abajo la pongo.

Answer (score 0):

El error estaba al sincronizar el proyecto con el targetSdkVersion = 28. Al tener el targetSdkVersion >=24, hay que colocar la siguiente linea en el onCreate:

StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder(); StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());

Al hacerlo damos acceso al archivo o carpeta particular y hacerlos accesibles para otras aplicaciones. De esa manera reemplazamos el file:// URI con content:// URI. De esta forma, la máquina virtual ignora la exposición URI del archivo.

Solución obtenida, como no... de:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed/41660839